# Block UI with Collapsed Navbar Dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website with a Navigation element that contains 5 menu items.

When the site is running on a mobile device or tablet, under 768px I would like the drop down menu to behave a little differently.

I would like the menu background to take up the entire screen when it is displayed, essentially blocking the UI.

Here is how the application looks now.
[image: this is when we do not click menu button]

And this is how I would like it to look once the menu button has been pressed. (Desired Results)
[image: and this is when we click menu button]

This is what I have tried, but have been unsuccessful.

```
<div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
        <!-- Toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 </button>
             </div>
             <div id="navbar-collapse-1" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right home-page-menu">
                     <li ng-repeat="(state, label) in menuItems"><a ui-sref="{{ state }}">{{ label }}</a></li>
                     <li><a href="" class="a-hiring"><button class="btn hiring">WE ARE HIRING</button></a></li>
                </ul>
           </div>
      </div><!-- end navbar-inner -->
 </nav>
```

Comment: So what is the problem you are having now?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any problem and the only clear thing is an ad poster, so I am flagging this as spam.

Comment: it's not spam, it's my problem, I try to explain, but I'm not good english, so I only post like this, Sorry if it make you are not uncomfortable.

Comment: @Niemand It's not spam, OP was just having trouble wording the question. I made an edit, it should be easier to understand when/if the edit gets approved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4rktL9q7/2/
I don't know if bootstrap gives you an easier way to do this but here is what you should do:

1) Wrap the popup navbar in a div

```
<div class="shadow"> 
    <h1> X </h1>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="">A</a></li>
       <li><a href="">B</a></li>
       <li><a href="">C</a></li>
       <li><a href="">D</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<nav class="mobile">
   <a> MENU </a>
</nav>
```

2) Set position to fixed, align it to top left corner and make it cover whole page by 100% width and height. Use text-align to center the menu and initially set the display to none

```
.shadow
   {
    position:fixed; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    z-index:5; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
 }

.shadow ul{
  list-style:none;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.shadow h1{
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
}
```

3) Finally write an easy onclick listener to pop it up and close it up

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".mobile").click(function(){
        $(".shadow").css("display", "block");
   });

   $(".shadow h1").click(function(){
      $(".shadow").css("display", "none");
   });
})
```